# django-allauth social network error

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using `django all-auth` for authenticating users via social networks so, when I'm trying to login via `facebook/google/twitter` through url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/socialnetwork/login
```

( here `socialaccount` is facebook/google/twitter), I'm able to login successfully and then getting redirected to:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
```

but when I'm going to url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/socialnetwork/login/callback/
```

I'm getting this error "an error occured while logging via social network" but could see "signout" and "change email" options if I'm already logged in.

Also,when I'm going to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/social/connections/
```

sometimes I can see only google and twitter accounts, sometimes only facebook accounts but not both depending upon my site_id in settings.py.
Now I'm really confused whether this is an issue with my callback urls or my site domains or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that visitting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/socialnetwork/login/` (where I assume `socialnetwork` is one of google/twitter/facebook) works fine. Congratulations! -- because these are the proper entry points for logging in with a third party provider.

You should not be visitting the callback url directly yourself. It is meant to be redirected to by the third party provider. In doing so, it passes along authentication related codes that can be used to login. If you visit the url directly these codes are not passed, hence, the system will complain with "an error has occurred"...

As for the issue with respect to the social connections url: what you see here is all third party accounts connected to the local user account. So, if it varies from time to time I can only assume you are logging in under different accounts - which implies different connected third party accounts.

Comment: I logged in to my facebook,google,twitter accounts through local host using django-allauth simultaneously,but what I observed is that while I try to retrieve data from all of them ( facebook ,google ,twitter) and put it in one html page,I could only get either facebook information or both google and twitter information,depending upon which thirdy party account I explicitly visited(such as if I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/ for the last time I get only facebook information in my page)

Answer (score 0):

There is a fair amount of confusion for me around what values go where, there is an APP_ID from Twitter that seems to be useless unless you are filing a support request but somehow from the docs I got the idea that that was the value I needed to put into the CLIENT_ID, but NO, you need to put in the API_KEY there....  The lack of good logging/display of the errors by the template (because of a malformed exception text) makes it hard to figure out what is going on.  Luckily I set a breakpoint and found the real error, changed the values around and voila, it was working....

Not sure who is at fault here, allauth or twitter, but it would help if everyone could get on the same page when it comes to naming things.